# Specifying Boolean in Sanic Routing Parameter

Tags: python, sanic

In Sanic, [one may specify various primitive types in the incoming URL's route parameters](http://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sanic/routing.html#request-parameters), such as `<param:int>` or `<param:number>`, so that the function receiving the request parameters can have the types parsed correctly, automatically.

However, `<param:bool>` doesn't work. Is Boolean not supported in Sanic, or did I use an incorrect keyword?

My error message:

```
Error: Requested URL /api/True not found
```

My code:

```
app.add_route(APIController().entry, '/api/<param:bool>)
```

I have also tried other spellings such as Boolean and BooleanType to no avail. Version of Sanic is 0.7.0 with Python 3.6.5 in virtualenv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in [sanic codebase here](https://github.com/channelcat/sanic/blob/212da1029e9a0ed786b5a1bfaf10183bfef9a790/sanic/router.py#L105-L107), if the type of the parameter is unknown sanic will just use the `default` type which is `str`.

The known types are [defined here](https://github.com/channelcat/sanic/blob/212da1029e9a0ed786b5a1bfaf10183bfef9a790/sanic/router.py#L16):

```
REGEX_TYPES = {
    'string': (str, r'[^/]+'),
    'int': (int, r'\d+'),
    'number': (float, r'[0-9\\.]+'),
    'alpha': (str, r'[A-Za-z]+'),
    'path': (str, r'[^/].*?'),
    'uuid': (uuid.UUID, r'[A-Fa-f0-9]{8}-[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-'
             r'[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-[A-Fa-f0-9]{12}')
}
```

So no, there is no `bool` type.